# Understanding joint probability distributions

Tags: probability

[image]

### Attempt

What is required to find is $P(X+Y \geq 1 )$. By definition,

$$ P(X+Y \geq 1 ) = \int \int\limits_{ \{ (x,y) : x+y \geq 1 } f_{XY} f(x,y) $$

We also want that $x \in [0,1]$ and $y \in [0,2]$. So after setting up my region I end up

$$ \int_{-1}^1 \int_{1-x}^2 (2x+2-y) dy dx $$

Is this the correct set up? is this how to approach this type of problems? OR is there a way with less computations?

Comment: I would say $\int_0^1$.. why do you make it start from $-1$? $x \in [0, 1]$, no? Also, I don't see where the $\frac 14$ ended up. But anyhow, yes, this is the correct way to go about it :) If you have a lot of these probabilities, though, you can first compute the density of $X+Y$ directly (in a very similar manner). This can be convenient instead of doing the same integral several times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite right, $x$ doesn't take negative value also we can't get rid of the denominator.

$$ \int_{\color{red}0}^1 \int_{1-x}^2 \frac{(2x+2-y)}{\color{red}4} \,\,dy dx $$